# Deleted iTunes matched songs still taking up space

Tags: ssd, itunes-match

I recently turned on iTunes Match and opted to delete local copies of my music. After doing so, my available space on my SSD did not report a change, despite deleting almost 100GB of tracks. Is this data cached somewhere on my SSD and the OS will manage this for me as I add new files to the drive, or do I need to manually do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this was a bit of user error. I did not click the remove from computer option, so the files remained in my music folder.

Comment: You've answered your own question. Mark it as the answer to close the question please

Comment: I will do so in 2 days, I tried earlier and I was told I have to wait.